# Criar um ALIAS para o um ./configure File?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, alias

Clonei o repositorio do Github, e para executar o comando preciso sempre digitar, ./nome-do-diretorio/vv

Imagino que esse "arquivo" seja do tipo CONFIGURE do Linux, correto?

Gostaria de saber como eu crio um ALIAS no Ubuntu para que quando eu digite apenas "vv" ele execute esse comando globalmente de qualquer lugar da minha maquina...

E se possivel poderiam adicionar o mesmo processo para o OSX (Mac)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente o `alias` é colocado no arquivo `~/.bashrc`, supondo que você use o [**Bash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Para editar o arquivo, digite no terminal:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

E adicione o `alias` no final:

```
alias cmd='comando'
```

Também é possível criar um arquivo de `aliases` separado, assim você não terá que colocá-los no `.bashrc`, mas em um arquivo de sua escolha. Primeiro, edite o arquivo `~/.bashrc` e descomente as seguintes linhas:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Salve e feche o arquivo. Depois disso, tudo o que você tem a fazer é criar o arquivo `~/.bash_aliases` e adicionar seus `aliases` lá.

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente... Eu criei um ALIAS assim: alias vv='./vv/vv' certo? Essa pasta VV esta na /home/joaopaulo/ e so pode ser executada se eu estiver na /home/joaopaulo/ eu queria poder executar esse comando de qualquer lugar do sistema, seja em Documentos ou o Desktop, queria essa acessibilidade poderia me ajudar a tornar esse comando "global" (imagino que seja essa a palavra)

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Bom, se a pasta `vv` está na sua *home*, basta indicar na `alias` assim: `vv='$HOME/vv/vv'` deve funcionar. =)

Comment: @qmechanick Funcionou!!!! Muito Obrigado!!!